# PHP GTK short path

Tags: php, windows, image, gtk, gtk2

I have the following [**PHP GTK**](http://gtk.php.net/) code located in `C:\gtk`

```
<?php
if (!class_exists('gtk')) {
    die("Please load the php-gtk2 module in your php.ini\r\n");
}

$wnd = new GtkWindow();
$wnd->set_title('Background');
$wnd->set_resizable(false);
$wnd->set_position(GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);

$wnd->connect_simple('destroy', array('gtk', 'main_quit'));

$im = GtkImage::new_from_file("C:\gtk\bg.jpg");
$wnd->add($im);

$wnd->show_all();
Gtk::main();
?>
```

It **shows the image** `C:\gtk\bg.jpg` but my question is **how can I display it from a local path.**  The PHP file **is located in that folder** so I should ***only*** have to type `bg.jpg` but **that doesn't work.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**

```
$im = GtkImage::new_from_file(dirname(__FILE__)."\bg.jpg");
```